# How can i convert ascii code to arabic 1256 code page character in c#?

Tags: c#

in c# windows application write the simple program ,that program get arabic 1256 character and show to user that ascii code,for that purpose write this code:

```
    string value = textBox1.Text;
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (byte b in System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.ToCharArray()))
    {
        label2.Text="Ascii Code="+b.ToString();
        counter++;
    }
```

now want to write code get ascii code and show to user arabic 1256 character,how can i write code for that purpose in c#?thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
char ch = Convert.ToChar(64);
```

or with using simply:

```
char ch = (char)64;
```

Comment: In c++, is there any ways to convert ASCII to Arabic?